# when I write findAll it says: findAll is not defined

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, anaconda

I am trying to write my first data scraping code. However, this happens whenever I try and find all the tr tags in the html:

I wrote: match = findAll("tr",{"class":"match"})
This comes up: NameError: name "findAll" is not defined.

Comment: how to use BeautifulSoup
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am assuming right and you are using

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

you need to understand that find_all is part of the bs4.element.Tag object
findAll might not work

```
obj = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
obj.find_all("tr",{"class":"match"})
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: `findAll` is bs3 syntax, and `find_all` is bs4 syntax. But bs4 has backward compatibility, so, as of now, `findAll` does work (but, is deprecated, so it's better to use `find_all`).

Comment: Whenever I try findAll , I end up with an error that says None type object is not callable , because my Soupobj.findAll is None.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with `findAll`. Can't reproduce it. But, anyway, there's no need of using bs3 syntax in bs4. So, keep using `find_all`.